# Обработка ошибки 404 Spring

Tags: java, spring

Есть сервер, построенный на Spring + Hibernate. Небходимо отловить ошибку 404 когда пользователь стучиться на неправильный адрес (например localhost:8080/tes вместо test). Для этого я написал `GlobalExceptionHandlerController.class`. В нем отлично отлавливаются все ошибки кроме 404. В чем проблема?

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandlerController {
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = NullPointerException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public String handleNullPointerException(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("A null pointer exception ocurred " + e);
        return "nullpointerExceptionPage";
    }


    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public String handleAllException(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("A unknow Exception Ocurred: " + e);
        return "unknowExceptionPage";
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ResponseBody
    public String handleResourceNotFoundException() {
        return "notFoundJSPPage";
    }
}
```

Comment: Дело в том что 404 ошибка не является исключением, поэтому не отлавливаеься. Вам надо писать фильтр для отлова 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Клиент может может получить `HTTP 404` по 2 причинам: **при обращении по ошибочному url-адресу** (`localhost:8080/tes` вместо `localhost:8080/test`) или **при обращении к несуществующему ресурсу** (`localhost:8080/test/42`, а объекта с ключом 42 не существует).

На самом деле с точки зрения протокола http, это все одна и та же ошибка - обращение к несуществующему ресурсу, а разделение сделано для того, чтобы показать отличия в обработке обоих ситуаций.

В 1м случае, при обращении по ошибочному url-адресу ошибку 404 вернет Spring (т.к. не будет найдено соответствующего маппинга для url-адреса). Чтобы указать страницу, возвращаемую в таком случае, вы должны указать ее в конфиге. При конфигурировании с помощью xml, будет примерно так:

```
</web-app>
    ...
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/pages/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Во 2м случае, например при обращении по `localhost:8080/test/42` вызывается соответствующий метод контроллера и внутри него вы понимаете, что объекта с ключом 42 не существует. Вы выбрасываете какое-то свое исключение, например называемое `ResourceNotFoundException`, а в `ControllerAdvice` добавляете обработку этого исключения, где будете перенаправлять на нужную страницу.